# Magento Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cat_index_position' in 'order clause'

Tags: php, mysql, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

I am getting a error as below and I have no clue how to solve this error as I am  new to magento. It would also help me if there is some description of the error format. The main reason I am not able to solve this is because I don't understand this error in first place.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:638:"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cat_index_position' in 'order clause', query was: SELECT DISTINCT `e`.`attribute_set_id` FROM `catalog_product_flat_11` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=11 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '393' AND cat_index.is_parent=1
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 ORDER BY `cat_index_position` ASC, `cat_index`.`position` ASC LIMIT 12";i:1;s:4448:"#0 /home1/poojakit/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home1/poojakit/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home1/poojakit/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#4 /home1/poojakit/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT DISTINCT...', Array)
#5 /home1/poojakit/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(794): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php(1096): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchCol(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php(290): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection->getSetIds()
#8 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer.php(220): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer->_getSetIds()
#9 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(163): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer->getFilterableAttributes()
#10 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(122): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->_getFilterableAttributes()
#11 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(293): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->_prepareLayout()
#12 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#13 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/local/MGS/Mpanel/Helper/Data.php(3267): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('catalog/layer_v...')
#14 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/design/frontend/mgstheme/default/template/mgs/mpanel/template/layout/category/right.phtml(7): MGS_Mpanel_Helper_Data->renderContent('218')
#15 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home1/poojakit...')
#16 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/mgsthe...')
#17 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#18 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#19 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/local/MGS/Mpanel/Helper/Data.php(3091): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/design/frontend/mgstheme/cetus/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(106): MGS_Mpanel_Helper_Data->getCategoryRight()
#21 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home1/poojakit...')
#22 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/mgsthe...')
#23 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#24 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#26 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#27 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/local/MGS/Mpanel/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(143): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#28 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): MGS_Mpanel_Catalog_CategoryController->viewAction()
#29 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#30 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#31 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#32 /home1/poojakit/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#33 /home1/poojakit/public_html/index.php(88): Mage::run('', 'store')
#34 {main}";s:3:"url";s:48:"/index.php/poojakits/pooja-items/pooja-kits.html";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:2:"en";}
```

Comment: The obvious conclusion is that that column is not in any of the selected tables.

Comment: any clue to solve this?

Comment: Queries in Magento are generated, so it's almost certainly some line modifying the query incorrectly. A hint is that the position is in the order by twice but only the second looks correct.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that this is a Magento bug that occurs when Flat Categories and/or Products is enabled and a block calls addAttributeToSort() of a product collection.  The column in the 'order by' clause should be `cat_index`.`position` instead of `cat_index_position`.

I found [this extension](https://github.com/Webtise/cat-index-position-fix) that claims to solve the problem, although I have not tested it yet myself.

Comment: Could you write where in core it happens? Experiencing this problem on random categories whilst others not.. have done full reindex without luck.. thinking to patch it.

Comment: The extension seem to solve it indead, at least from initial testing, I made it into a patch however.

Answer (score 0):

Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer->getFilterableAttributes().

Is resulting in this query.

I suggest you reindex attributes and then check again.

Probably you have added or deleted some attribute and the DB logical relations are not in place.

In case this does not work then you need to check the community modules that are handling attributes.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a Magento bug that occurs when *Flat Categories* and/or Products is enabled and a block calls `addAttributeToSort()` of a product collection.
You need to configure:

Admin > Store > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Use Flat Catalog Product >
choose **No** and clear cache.

The problem will be solved.